# Meteor: Router with URL of a userName?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have problems with creating routes with user's usernames. So idea is something like this: Click on path and go to that users profile. His link should be something like : http://www.something.com/usersUsername
I was reading and trying everything I found on internet about this but lot of stuff changed so I couldn't manage this.
Only thing I found usefull is that when page loads client ,,watch" paths first and then subscribes to a collection so I got ,,null" for path. Any help? My idea is to create something to waitOn for subscribe...

*Packages*: **iron:router** , **accounts-ui** , **accounts-password**

Here is code:

**Start page, template:**

```
<template name="početna">
<h1>Dobrodošli!</h1>
<h3>Registrujte se:</h3>
    {{> register}}
<h3>Prijavite se:</h3>
    {{> login}}

{{#if currentUser}}
    <h2>Logovan si!</h2>
    {{> logout}}
    <a href="{{pathFor route='profil' username=username }}">Profil</a>
{{/if}}
```

**Router JS file:**

```
    Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'okvir'
});

// *  * * * *  * //

Router.route('/', {
    name: 'početna', 
    template: 'početna',
});

Router.route('/:username',  {
   waitOn: function(){
       return Meteor.subscribe('userData'), Meteor.user().username
          },    
    name: 'profil',
    template: 'profil',
    
});
```

**Simple HTML template file only to se if it works:**

```
<template name="profil">    
    <h1>RADI</h1>
</template>
```

**Thanks!**

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing? Is the value of `Meteor.user().username` null inside `waitOn` or `username` is null inside `template`?

Comment: Before I added waitOn console sad that null inside waitOn, now I don't know why am I getting null in username or how to fix this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luna, thanks for help! Luna's answer helped but I also needed:
1.) Helper to set value of username=username

```
Template["početna"].helpers({ username: function() { return  Meteor.user().username } })
```

2.) Publish

```
   Meteor.publish("userData", (username) => {
    return Meteor.users.find({
        username: username
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
Router.route('/:username',{
    name: 'profil',
    waitOn: function () {
        return Meteor.subscribe('userData', this.params.username)
    },

    action: function () {
        this.render('profil', {
            data: function () {
                return Meteor.users.findOne({username: this.params.username});
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**EDIT**:

With `this.params.username` will let anybody visit that profile, user or not. If you want to prevent that, you can use `onBeforeAction()`

```
onBeforeAction: function() {
    if(Meteor.user() && this.params.username == Meteor.user().username){
        this.next();
    } else {
        Router.go('/not-authorized') //or any other route
    }
},
```

Comment: I'm still getting http://localhost:3000/null :/ .. Only new now is that I see "Loading..." on page.